# Copy text to clipboard: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'writeText'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, copy-paste

I have a button

[image]

When I clicked on COPY

```js
copyImageLinkText({ mouseenter, mouseleave }, e) {
  this.showCopiedText = !this.showCopiedText
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.imageLink)

  clearTimeout(this._timerId)
  mouseenter(e)
  this._timerId = setTimeout(() => mouseleave(e), 1000)
},
```

This line seems to work perfectly locally on my MacBook Pro

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.imageLink)
```

It's **not** working when I build and deployed it to my dev server.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')

[image]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The use of `navigator.clipboard` requires a secure origin. So if your dev environment is being served over HTTP, then the clipboard method won't be available.

*According to MDN [`Clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) docs*

> This feature is available only in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) (HTTPS), in some or all [supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard#browser_compatibility).

Maybe you could check if this method is available with `window.isSecureContext`, and disable the Copy Text button accordingly.

---

#### Workaround

The best option is to use HTTPS in your dev environment.

But since you asked for a workaround, here's a (very hacky) working method. Using [`Document.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)  command, which is no longer recommended, in favour of [`ClipboardAPI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API).

```js
function unsecuredCopyToClipboard(text) {
  const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();
  try {
    document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unable to copy to clipboard', err);
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
```

#### Usage

You can then just check if `!navigator.clipboard` and call the fallback method, otherwise continue with the normal `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...)` function. For example:

```js
const unsecuredCopyToClipboard = (text) => { const textArea = document.createElement("textarea"); textArea.value=text; document.body.appendChild(textArea); textArea.focus();textArea.select(); try{document.execCommand('copy')}catch(err){console.error('Unable to copy to clipboard',err)}document.body.removeChild(textArea)};

/**
 * Copies the text passed as param to the system clipboard
 * Check if using HTTPS and navigator.clipboard is available
 * Then uses standard clipboard API, otherwise uses fallback
*/
const copyToClipboard = (content) => {
  if (window.isSecureContext && navigator.clipboard) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content);
  } else {
    unsecuredCopyToClipboard(content);
  }
};
```

```html
<button onClick="buttonPress()">➡️ Copy Message to Clipboard</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> const buttonPress = () => { copyToClipboard('Hello World!'); console.log('Clipboard updated \nNow try pasting!'); }; </script>
```

Comment: how then `navigator.clipboard` works on localhost that has http?

Comment: @bpGusar Locally-delivered resources are also considered secure, as there's no opportunity for an external actor to use a MITM attack :) See the [When is a context considered secure?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts#when_is_a_context_considered_secure) section in the MDN docs for more info.

Comment: Upvote for the Information about it will only work with SSL

Comment: `document.execCommand` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use an `async` and put your code in `try catch` block.

```js
async copyCode() {
 try {
     await navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.input);
 } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some addition for the answer, that was useful for me, scroll with `preventScroll` parameter as an argument for the scroll func, since the input will be removed, you probable won't need scroll to it

```js
 textArea.focus({preventScroll: true})
```